# Animations for smooth transitions and Collisions during certain animations in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, collision

I expected my animation to jump and it did lift off the ground and I expected my attack animation to initiate however it did not. Colliding with enemies causes no transition because the whole body cannot find a collider or trigger. I mean, I cannot find which trigger is affected by animations compared to simple sprites that do not animate and just use boxcollider2D's to sense triggers from other objects in the scene.

Here is how I set up my animation's transition from one state to another. An AnimatorStateInfo variable equal to GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0); is compared to a string stored as an integer using Animator.StringToHash("..."); but it never worked for me. My gameObject has only two states: Idle or Defend. Right now it only has one and that's Idle. Which string goes into the StringToHash function? is it the name of the Animation itself, or is it the name of a certain parameter? I'll show you code and leave notes. please inquire ...

```
int idleHash = Animator.StringToHash("...");
//stored as an integer and I Don't Know what to put into the 
//parenthesis.
//Then a function is called to go into the Defend Animation.

void defendStart()    {
    AnimatorStateInfo Variable1 = GetComponent<Animator>.  
    ().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
//Keep in mind the next IF statement is compared with an integer   
//stored value given to us by the Animator and this is where I'm  
//not sure if the string for the nameHash is related to a certain  
//parameter or if it's the title of the Animation itself
    if (stateInfo.nameHash == idleHash)    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Defend", true);
                                            }
                       }
```

The Defend Animation was very slow to respond and better off not working at all until I can find and implement the proper method. Before implementing these methods into the script, I also tried to implement the same trigger concept as is to non-animated sprites but this did not work. I had questions about whether the OnTriggerStay2D or OnTriggerExit2D or OnTriggerEnter2D functions worked with animations or if there is a completely different method. Thank you for any responses. Please shed some light.

Comment: I meant Defend Animation NOT Attack Animation in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out! In C-Sharp (C#) it is all done with strings and the entire nameHash/fullPathHash method must be for something else. Instead of accessing our Animation state with AnimatorStateInfo and comparing that variable to a nameHash, we do it with AnimatorClipInfo and identify the clip name. The clip name specifies what animation is currently playing and that we are ready to transition into the next animation. Here is the code that worked:

```
AnimatorClipInfo[0] m_AnimClipInfo;
string m_ClipName;

//Then a function is called to go into the defend   
//animation.

void defendStart()
{
    m_AnimClipInfo = this.GetComponent<Animator>.  
    ().GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);
    m_ClipName = m_AnimClipInfo[0].clip.name;
    Debug.Log(m_ClipName);

//without this next IF statement, animations would lag,  
//skip, or otherwise not begin immediately on call.

//Where it says, '(name of your animation)' you put the 
//Debug.Log function's output.

    if (m_ClipName == "(name of your animation)")
    {
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Defend", true);
    }
}
```